# Weird drive conflict in windows 10 with some programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, raid, raid-1

I've got a RAID1, and an EX-RAID1 that was de-raided and is now a standard disk.   In some programs, such as the duplicate finder I use, it seems to think both are the same disk. i.e. :E:\<->L:\, Both drive letters point to the same location, please fix conflict or false duplicates will result"

I know they're not the same disk, and everything I can check is different between them-- including GUID in the registry, drive serial number, volume serial number, volume label, etc.

Any clue what might be going on, and more importantly, how to fix it? I need to have any unique files that remain on the second disk, off it  and have it wiped by Tuesday, if at all possible.

EDIT: While I can't check via USB (and running a 10TB on USB is insane anyways), I've also tried changing it by "mapping to a network drive", just changing the drive letters, and switching SATA ports around.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!  Apparently there's a partition serial#-- which is different from the drive's serial#, apparently, and the volume ID visible in windows.

That matched on both drives, and changing it-- once I found a program that could--- solved everything!